# how can i deploy my nextjs into a sub dir on my server but not the root dir

Tags: next.js

i am study nextjs and i have a problem
how i can deploy the app into a sub dir like '/next' in my server but not the root dir
i try to deploy into a dir named '/next'
but after that my static files which in the public folder can not be access:
[image]
the url it request is not right ,it should be '/next/tell.png' instead of '/tell.png'

another question is about js files in pages 
the js file url should be '/pages/curise.js' but not the '/page/next/curisejs'

Oh here is my next.config.js i define the assetPrefix and basePath 
when env is production ,it will be '/next'
i will use it when the router be changed

guys pls help me
[image]

[image]